# Retrieving files from Sybase

Tags: sql, blob, sap-ase

I am using Sybase ASE and we have word, pdfs and other file types stored as BLOB in our database. I have to extract those files from sybase.

What would be the easiest way of extracting those file? Is there Sybase function that I could use?

Thanks

I have tried TSQL and JDBC Java connection but none of it is working for me.

Comment: Can't you just use a `SELECT my_clob from my_table` using a simple JDBC connection? I've done it. What error do you get?

Comment: I want to extract files out of sybase. I am using OLE Automation procedure in Sybase ASE. Does Sybase ASE supports OLE Automation Procedure? Have any idea?